# Trying to scrape through selenium but cannot iterate through dynamic content

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, iterator

I'm trying to **scrape** this website. I get the first set of data but when I try to iterate with a for loop it returns an error. I've tried changing user_data class name numerous times but it still refuses to iterate.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get('https://soundcloud.com/jujubucks')
print(driver.title)

user_data = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('userStreamItem')

for user in user_data:
    search = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//span[@class="soundTitle__usernameText"]')
    search_song = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//span[@class=""]')
    search_date = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//span[@class="sc-visuallyhidden"]')
    stats = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.soundStats.sc-ministats-group .sc- 
    visuallyhidden')

    print(f'''

    Artist: {search.text}
    Song Title: {search_song.text}
    Upload Date: {search_date.text}
    Track Plays: {stats.text}

    ''')

    driver.quit()
```

Comment: In the `for` loop, it should be `search = user.find_element_by_xpath(...)"`
Logic: You want to iterate through the `user_data`. Right now, you're iterating through `driver` which (as expected) would return an error!

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues here.
To pick the data from all the songs initially presented on the page you can do this:

```py
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains


PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
actions = ActionChains(driver)

driver.get('https://soundcloud.com/jujubucks')
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))).click()

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".userStreamItem")))
time.sleep(1)
songs = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('userStreamItem')
for i in range(1, len(songs)+1):
    song = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"(//div[@class='userStreamItem'])[{i}]")
    actions.move_to_element(song).perform()
    time.sleep(0.5)
    search_song = song.find_element_by_xpath('.//span[@class=""]')
    search_date = song.find_element_by_xpath('.//span[@class="sc-visuallyhidden"]')
    stats = song.find_element_by_xpath(".//ul[@class='soundStats sc-ministats-group']//span[@class='sc-visuallyhidden']")
    print(f'''

    Artist: {search.text}
    Song Title: {search_song.text}
    Upload Date: {search_date.text}
    Track Plays: {stats.text}

    ''')
```

But this will grab only 5 first songs data. To get more you will have to scroll the page

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\houst\PycharmProjects\The Machine App\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 169, in _new_conn
    conn = connection.create_connection(
  File "C:\Users\houst\PycharmProjects\The Machine App\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 96, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "C:\Users\houst\PycharmProjects\The Machine App\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 86, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made

Comment: it still refuses to iterate for the other songs after the first one.

Comment: And this error was not before my code added?